# Get an attributes value of the ALT attribute of a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

My a-tag (link) contains innerHTML which is an image like this:

```
.innerHTML = <img alt="hello world" src="/Content/Images/test.png">
```

How can I get the text of the `alt` attribute with JQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being `$a` your `<a/>` element.

Using jQuery you can do:

```
$("img", $a).first().attr("alt");
```

---

Or, using pure JavaScript:

```
var $img = $a.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
console.log($img.alt);
```

​
[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xnkjn/)

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `.first()`? is this to circumvent any issues with multiple image elements in a single anchor tag?

Comment: Alexander you were the first answering my question WITH Jquery which I asked for so your answer is the solution.

Answer (score 11):

You really don't need jQuery. If you have the a element you can do this:

```
// lets call the anchor tag `link`
var alt = link.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt; // assuming a single image tag
```

Remember attributes map to properties (most), and unless the property is changed, or the attribute, the two should reflect the same data (there are edge cases to this, but they can be handled case-by-case).

If you truly do need the attribute there is

```
var alt = link.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('alt');
```

Last scenario is if you only have the image tag as a string.

```
var str = '<img alt="hello world" src="/Content/Images/test.png">';
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = str;
var alt = tmp.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
```

If you must use jQuery (or just prefer it) then the other answer provided by Alexander and Ashivard will work.

Note: My answer was provided for completeness and more options. I realize the OP asked for jQuery solution and not native js.

Comment: @Elisa, The other solutions were what you asked for, however knowing the alternatives and why is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
var altName=$('a img').attr('alt');
```

Comment: This isn't really that helpful if there are multiple anchors with images in them. If the OP wants to process this value or collect it for multiple anchors your code fails.