# Concatenate different textContext of a tag and img alt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to parse HTML with DOM javascript; Here's the input :

```
<span class="MATH">d<img width="34" height="39" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1915.gif" alt="$ \,y^{k}/$">d<img width="16" height="17" align="BOTTOM" border="0" src="img     1893.gif" alt="$ \,s$"></span>
```

I would like to transform it in the following output :

```
<span class="MATH">d$ \,y^{k}/$d$\,s$</span>
```

As you can, I have to concatenate the first textContent element of span.MATH ("`d`") with the first alt attribute of img tag ("`$\,y^{k}/$`"), and with the second textContent element of span.MATH ("`d`") and the second alt attribute of img tag ("`$\,s$`").

I would like to do the following thing, i.e use a main loop for select all `span.MATH` and an inner loop for all child `img tags` :

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('span.MATH'),function(span) {
                                      [].forEach.call(span.querySelectorAll('img'),function(img) {                       
 I am looking for a method to set automatically : span.innerHTML = "d";
                            var alt_text = img.getAttribute('alt');
                            span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML+alt_text;
            });
```

How to extract automatically, at each occurence of `img tag`, the letter "`d`" wich precedes the `img tag` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
img.alt
```

See this question at stackoverflow: [Get an attributes value of the ALT attribute of a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940976/get-an-attributes-value-of-the-alt-attribute-of-a-hyperlink)

Comment: you didn't understand my question. I want to store the text before each <img> occurence into span.MATH.

Comment: Can you insert your code at jsfiddle? This will help me to try solve your problem