# alt textContent in JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get the text out of an Alt element in the DOM. 
Can anyone please advise what the best way to do this is. 
I have added the code. I'm trying to get the details of the product so I can put it in an object:

```
<div class="product col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" alt="0001|Plain White T-Shirt|4.99|M|White|25|Mens-Tshirts">
        <a href="/0001/product">
            <img class="productImage" src="/static/store/images/products/plainWhiteTShirt.jpeg">
        </a>
        <a href="/0001/product">
        <h3>Plain White T-Shirt</h3>
        </a>
        <h4 class="price">£4.99</h4>
        <input type="button" class="button style_one addToCartOne" value="Add To Cart">
    </div>
```

I need to get things like the size, price, color, etc.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried ? Retrieve the string from `alt` attribute and then split it with `|` or use a regex

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a free code writing service. You're supposed to exhaust all available resources before asking here. It looks like you haven't even used Google yet. First result for "js read alt": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940976/get-an-attributes-value-of-the-alt-attribute-of-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vanilla Javascript you can use:

```
document.querySelector('.product[alt]').getAttribute('alt').split('|');
```

Then you receive an array that you can iterate with a map or forEach, like this:

```
document.querySelector('.product[alt]').getAttribute('alt').split('|').map(item => console.log(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to add some id

```
<div id="your_id" class="product ...
```

on element and by using `document.getElementById('your_id').getAttribute('alt')` code, get the text value. But if it is not possible, you can use attribute-selector combined with class-selector for getting it:

```
document.querySelector('.product[alt^=0001]').getAttribute('alt')
```

For more on attribute selectors look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)